# Text field wrongly shown together with mobiscroll

Tags: javascript, html, css, mobiscroll

I'm trying to set up a mobiscroll number chooser for a landing page, but it seems that I'm doing something wrong because, above the scroll, I get a text field with the number chosen in mobiscroll written inside it.

To be honest, in the website I didn't find a very easily understandable FAQ for the installation and I'm a bit new to this kind of things, could please someone help me?
Below a screen of the page and the code as well.

[image]

[The code here](https://mobiscroll.googlegroups.com/attach/e8bc48a6ee3a92c5/mobiscroll_number_select.rar?gda=uM2Dy0cAAAD-XxA0Ng2wKbdsf0VkTXmr6QVK_bXlH66btbQ50mJ38BCxNgLvxLagzxoJSt5nJeobQwFxJw55cVwemAxM-EWmeV4duv6pDMGhhhZdjQlNAw&gsc=hGpCNwoAAABHneRcm_9zoPuM39F6fyHo&pli=1&part=4)

Comment: Where do you wanna show the text box?

Comment: http://winegood.it/landing_ristoranti/index.html    here, beside the picture (I will resize it)

Comment: Remove display:none !important from the inline style

Comment: And R u sure that all js&CSS3 files are in given path?

Comment: But if I remove that the mobiscroll comes with no style (just a simple list), you can try it with firebug to see what I mean..

Comment: @Sowmya omg thank you so much, all that copy and paste made me forget about the path! how silly of me...Two days to find that out...   Only one last thing, I put a sort of label (textfield, the label isn't working, but I think that works the same) under the mobiscroll (I'll move inside the text later), but the problem is, how do I make it display also the first number even if hasn't been selected by the user? now when you load the page, nothing is displayed inside the "label", I'd like to see the firs number as well, I tried with option  selected="selected" but it isn't working...

Comment: For this you need to check in js

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `input{display:none}` in css file. It works.

I assumed that you don't want the text box to be shown.

---

*The below line in js file is inserting a input box before the select list.*

```
var input = $('<input type="text" id="' + id + '" value="' + main['_' + elm.val()] + '" class="' + s.inputClass + '" readonly />').insertBefore(elm);
```

Comment: thanks, that worked, but unfortunately there is another problem: if I try to put mobiscroll inside another web page, it doesn't appear... http://winegood.it/landing_ristoranti/index.html  is it because of **style="display:none !important;"** ?